# Minimum sample size for Cronbach Alpha?

Tags: sample-size, cronbachs-alpha

What should be the minimum number of people in a sample for finding cronbach alpha for:

1. Questtionaire with 20 items (Likert scale)
2. Test with 20 items (multiple choice)

A sample of 10, 20 or 40 ? 
Total population is 200,

Thank you for your answers
:-)

Answer (score 1):

[This simulation study](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/268809872_Minimum_Sample_Size_for_Cronbach%27s_Coefficient_Alpha_A_Monte_Carlo_Stdy) attempted to answer the question. Essentially, it depends on the size of the largest eigenvalue.
As the largest eigenvalue increases, the required sample size for unbiased estimation decreases. $N=30$ may be sufficient depending on the value of largest eigenvalue, so the article is worth checking out.

This other article may also be worth reading: [On the Use, the Misuse, and the Very Limited Usefulness of Cronbach’s Alpha](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2792363/). It stresses the limited usefulness of Cronbach's $\alpha$. It would be strange if Cronbach's $\alpha$ was the major consideration in determining sample size.